Find old X11 "drifting/gravity" 2D flight game that used to be bundled with Solaris in the '95s
In the '95s, I used to play a X11 2D flight game, which I think was included as default on the UNIX (Solaris, if I remember well) running on then-top-notch SUN scientific workstations.
Does anyone remember that game and could tell me if it has been adapted under Linux ?
At work, we used these stations for scientific calculation, mostly FEM and material modelling, and at pauses, some of us played his game. If I remember well, you first had to launch a server process, then you launched a client process which connected to the server and you could play from multiple stations on one server.
In that game, you played a "spaceship" or "plane" symbolized by a small triangle, pitted against bots and other users' ships. You had a small gun and a limited amount of fuel. The map was made of land masses you couldn't hit,because hitting them destroyed you. There were various landmarks on the "shores", like attractor or repulsor zones, safe landing pads, refuelling tanks, and so.
It was fun, because it had infinite possibilities, made use of both dexterity and wit, was a mix of combat and exploration, and allowed for small sessions during work pauses.
I've searched for it throughout the internet, to no avail... I remember it had "gravity" in the name, but as including that word didn't give me anything, I might be wrong. It was very popular at the time, so it can't be completely forgotten !
Thanks in advance for any hint, this game is for me a kind of Proust's madeleine ^-^

Unfortunately, ID of games from memory & without media from the game itself is considered off-topic here. We have a list of alternative resources for such questions. Your question may also fall within the scope of our sister site [scifi.se] SE, which allows the ID of games with sci-fi elements. Consider posting there, but check their ID guidelines first.

Hi @galacticninja, thanks for the hint, I didn't know that...

YEEESSSS ! Found it !
Writing that question inspired me new search avenues and I finally found it, it's name is XPilot !
Some links :

Official site : http://www.xpilot.org/
Wikipedia page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPilot?wprov=sfla1
The list on which I initially found it : https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/funet/util/X11/games/action/INDEX.html
A very comprehensive site dedicated to it : http://budwin.net/insectoid/xpilot/xpnewbie.html
Even a FB page : https://www.facebook.com/people/XPilot/100053445204938/

